# Calculate $\sum_\limits{k=1}^{100}\left \lfloor \sqrt{k}+\frac{1}{k} \right \rfloor$

Tags: summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Determine: $\sum_\limits{k=1}^{100}\left \lfloor \sqrt{k}+\frac{1}{k} \right \rfloor$.

It's well-known that $x-1<\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, but this didn't help me at all.
I computed it and the sum equals 627, but I found no useful properties.

Comment: Is the bracket supposed to refer to the floor function?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I forgot to specify it.

Comment: Try it like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1557966/summation-of-greatest-integer-sum-k-1n-left-lfloor-sqrtk-right-rf?rq=1).

Comment: Note that $(\sqrt k+\frac1k)^2=k+\frac2{\sqrt k}+\frac1{k^2}<k+1$ for all but small $k$, hence you can use $\lfloor \sqrt k\rfloor$ for most summands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for $k\ge5$,
$$
\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}=\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}\gt\frac1k\tag{1}
$$
so that
$$
\sqrt{k}\lt\sqrt{k}+\frac1k\lt\sqrt{k+1}\tag{2}
$$
Taking the floor of $(2)$ says that
$$
\left\lfloor\sqrt{k}\right\rfloor\le\left\lfloor\sqrt{k}+\frac1k\right\rfloor\le\left\lfloor\sqrt{k+1}\right\rfloor\tag{3}
$$
The only time that $\left\lfloor\sqrt{k}\right\rfloor\lt\left\lfloor\sqrt{k+1}\right\rfloor$ is when $k+1$ is a perfect square, which, in light of $(2)$ means that $\left\lfloor\sqrt{k}+\frac1k\right\rfloor\lt\left\lfloor\sqrt{k+1}\right\rfloor$. Thus, we get that for $k\ge5$
$$
\left\lfloor\sqrt{k}+\frac1k\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\sqrt{k}\right\rfloor\tag{4}
$$
We can also verify $(4)$ for the case $k=4$.

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{100}\left\lfloor\sqrt{k}+\frac1k\right\rfloor
&=\overbrace{2+1+2+10}^{k=1,2,3,100}+\sum_{k=4}^{99}\left\lfloor\sqrt{k}\right\rfloor\\
&=15+\sum_{j=2}^9j\left((j+1)^2-j^2\right)\quad\text{floor times number of terms with that floor}\\
&=15+\sum_{j=2}^9\left(2j^2+j\right)\\
&=15+\sum_{j=2}^9\left(4\binom{j}{2}+3\binom{j}{1}\right)\\
&=15+\left[4\binom{j+1}{3}+3\binom{j+1}{2}\right]_1^9\\[3pt]
&=15+4\binom{10}{3}+3\binom{10}{2}-4\binom{2}{3}-3\binom{2}{2}\\[12pt]
&=15+480+135-0-3\\[18pt]
&=627
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 7):

$f(k)=\left \lfloor \sqrt{k}+\frac{1}{k} \right \rfloor$. We have $f(1)=2,\space f(2)=1,\space f(3)=2$ so $$\sum_\limits{k=1}^{100}\left \lfloor \sqrt{k}+\frac{1}{k} \right \rfloor=5+\sum_\limits{k=4}^{100}\left \lfloor \sqrt{k}+\frac{1}{k} \right \rfloor$$
Now, between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2-1$ one has $\sqrt{k}+\dfrac{1}{k}=n$ from which
$$\sum_\limits{k=4}^{100}\left \lfloor \sqrt{k}+\frac{1}{k} \right \rfloor=\sum_\limits{k=2}^{9}n(2n+1)+10=622$$

Thus $$\sum_\limits{k=1}^{100}\left \lfloor \sqrt{k}+\frac{1}{k} \right \rfloor=622+5=\color{red}{627}$$

Comment: (+1) I didn't see your answer before I posted mine, but yours is essentially the same, so I deleted it.

Comment: It is a situation that has happened to me many times but mainly because my writing in English requires more time than I would use to write in either Spanish or French. I do however think dear friend that you should have posted your post anyway. Regards.

Comment: By the way I have had a type with $\sqrt{k}+\dfrac{1}{k}=n$ without the symbol of floor function. I don't edit because this would imply a new publication.  I record it here.

Comment: I will undelete it because there is a bit of extra justification included in it.

Comment: Very well, you are right.